# Getting error while connecting helix.perforce - "Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT No such host is known."

Tags: perforce

Trying to connect `helix perforce cloud through P4` Client, getting below error.

`C:\Users\sagaraa>p4 -Cauto -p`

```
ssl:TestContinuousDelivery.sagaraagre.helix.perforce.com:1667 trust
    Perforce client error:
        Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
        No such host is known.
```

Please note that I am working behind company proxy, so not sure that could be the issue. Outside company premise it is working perfectly fine.
Please advice if any one is facing similar issue, or have any resolution.

When running command `p4 set` gives below output:

```
P4EDITOR=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe (set)
P4PORT=perforce:1666 (set)
P4USER=sagaraagre (set)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a programming problem, more suitable for superuser I imagine.

Comment: Type `p4 set` in command line, it will display the values of the P4 environment variables. The first step is to be sure you have an adress set for P4 PORT. Put the result in your question.

Comment: Perhaps a DNS or Firewall issue of some sort? `ping TestContinuousDelivery.sagaraagre.helix.perforce.com` works fine for me.

Comment: Have you contacted the administrators of your company proxy, to see if they can allow you to make a connection from inside your corporate network to the helix.perforce.com server? Note that the P4 protocol is **not** HTTP, so you'll need to get a separate policy rule installed in the network rules for the P4 protocol to port 1667 on helix.perforce.com

Answer (score 3):

For your `P4PORT` value, `perforce` is the server's hostname and `1666` is the port number.

If you ping that server I bet it won't find the host either:

```
C:\Windows\System32>ping perforce
Ping request could not find host perforce. Please check the name and try again.
```

If that's the case for you, you can either use the actual hostname or IP address for your Perforce server in `P4PORT`:

```
C:\Windows\System32>p4 set P4PORT=TestContinuousDelivery.sagaraagre.helix.perforce.com:1666
```

Or, if you're set on using `perforce` there, you can add it as an alias in your hosts file:

```
C:\Windows\System32>echo 1.2.3.4 TestContinuousDelivery.sagaraagre.helix.perforce.com perforce >> drivers\etc\hosts
```

`1.2.3.4` would be the IP address corresponding to `TestContinuousDelivery.sagaraagre.helix.perforce.com`, and you can always ping that hostname to find the IP.

As an aside, there does seem to be an ongoing issue where `p4 set`'s `P4PORT` doesn't keep in sync with `.p4qt\connectionmap.xml`'s `P4Port` value. Resetting `P4PORT`, like what was done above, is one way to resolve that.